# Matching parentheses with a RowFilter (regexFilter)

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowfilter

```
protected void searchFilter(String s, int n) 
{
        RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(s);
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(s, n);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        filters.add(rf);
    }
```

I am trying to match a string in a JTable, that contains parentheses. In the above code, the string parameter could be:
John (Smith)

And the column i'm searching in:

```
Jane (Doe)
John (Smith)
John (Smith)
Jack (Smith)
```

Where I want it to return:

```
John (Smith)
John (Smith)
```

But right now it doesn't return anything. I have looked at the documentation for Matcher, Pattern and RowFilter, but nothing has helped me so far.

Comment: are this true?? `Where I want it to return: John (Smith) John (Smith)`, isn't John (Smith) & Jack (Smith)

Comment: @mKorbel why not, the column contains `John (Smith)` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses are meta-characters in regular expressions. Hence you are actually trying to match `John Smith` (without parentheses). What you need to do is to escape them.

Java has a built-in function to escape all meta-characters automatically: [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). Run `s` through this function and it should fix it.

Also note that you might want to surround the pattern with `^...$`. Otherwise it would accept rows containing something like `This is John (Smith) foobar.` (because the regex is glad if it can match a substring of the input).